# Why is malloc()'s pool called a "heap"?

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory, heap

Can anyone explain why the pool of memory managed by `malloc()` / `free()` is called a heap?

Based on [1]: http://www.google.com/url?q=http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNHaQLotbBKKwYqxiiYWN1146BWzFw "Doug Lea's explanation of how his malloc() works",
it's not obvious that the data structure which we call a "heap" is being used at all.

Do we call it a "heap" because it's common for `malloc()` implementations to use best-fit selection of the memory chunk to return, and that's historically been implemented using a min-heap of chunks, sorted by chunk size?

Comment: The heap memory pool and the heap data structure have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699057/why-are-two-different-concepts-both-called-heap

Comment: A quick check shows that it is not listed in the index to Knuth volume 1 (which does include dynamic memory management structures). Therefore, it is obviously irrelevant and pointless to ask.

Comment: Also see: [What's the difference between "a" heap and "the" heap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756861/whats-the-relationship-between-a-heap-and-the-heap)

Comment: Because the stack provides a relatively structured allocation area that is governed by scoping rules, and the "rest" of memory is just requested "wherever" and piled about more or less randomly (like heaps of dirty laundry in some college students rooms).

Comment: Also note that "the stack" isn't a stack, since you have random access. Every part of RAM is... random access.

Comment: **It isn't!** At least, not officially...