# Why is the heap (as in where we put objects) called that?

Tags: heap, naming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the origin of the term “heap” for the free store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660855/what-is-the-origin-of-the-term-heap-for-the-free-store)

Why is the heap called the heap?  I mean the bit of memory which we dynamically allocate bits of.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a citation for this, but I've always believed it derives from "a place to put stuff; a bit like the stack only less organised".

A stack has strict rules about where you add and remove things, but a heap doesn't.