# What's the connection between the heap used in dynamic memory allocation and the data structure?

Tags: c++, data-structures, heap-memory, heap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are two different concepts both called “heap”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699057/why-are-two-different-concepts-both-called-heap)

I've googled around, but cannot find the answer for this question; what's the connection between the heap used in dynamic memory allocation and the data structure? Is memory organized on the heap in a way which is similar the the heap data structure? If so, this seems very strange, since fetching memory should be random access AFAIK (i.e, O(1)), but finding an item from a heap is not done in constant time.

So, is this just an overloaded meaning of heap, so to speak, or is there some kind of connection?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699057/why-are-two-different-concepts-both-called-heap.

Comment: Right you are... I did search before posting this question but I guess I missed this. Vote to close?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heap is a synonym for what the standard calls the free-store. In contrast to stacks, which is used for function calls, and function-local object storage, heaps grow in the opposite direction (top to bottom) on many implementations (as opposed to stacks -- which grow from bottom to top). Of course, none of these are required by the standard.

The heap data structure, on the other hand is completely different -- it is a specialized tree structure with certain properties.

It is possible some implementations use the heap data structure for free-store management, whence the name may have been derived. (See [buddy memory allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddy_memory_allocation).)

Answer (score 2):

No, the program heap is different from the heap data structure. In other words, no relation. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap) discusses the program heap in detail.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Any idea on why it uses the same name then? Just a coincidence or some historical meaning?

Comment: @John Doe: These two things use the same name for the same reason your handle ("John Doe") is so common.

Comment: @S.Lott: Point taken :P
@Amit Kumar: Great link, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no relation, but I admit the name can be confusing. The heap in memory is an array that the OS allocates to programs. A heap is implemented by programs for fast lookup.