# What is the difference between the heap and the free store?

Tags: c++, heap-memory

Originally a pedantics war on @Als answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159968/declaring-array-of-int/6159973#6159973), it also sparked a discussion in the C++ chatroom.

[This article](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/009.htm) by Herb Sutter distinguishes between the two, but is also over a decade old, as it clearly was written before 2000 and also talks about the standard **draft**, which can only mean C++98 draft. Though, I still expect Herb, as part of the committee, to be knowledgeable about this stuff.

I know of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660855/what-is-the-origin-of-the-term-heap-for-the-free-store) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350819/c-free-store-vs-heap) question/answer, but the second just cites Herb's article while the first cites another source that simply rejects the use of the term "heap", aka they are both not exactly satisfactory. Also, I can't find any `free-store` or `freestore` tag on SO (until this question, I created the former one now).

Now, what is *really* the difference, if any?

Comment: Check what [Bjarne Stroustrup has to say about this](http://zamanbakshifirst.blogspot.com/search/label/heap).

Comment: @Prasoon: Nice link! Now, why didn't you post that as an answer? :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Well, the current C++ standard only uses the term "free store" - the only use of "heap" in the Standard is to describe the heap data structure in the Standard Library. So "heap" is not a very useful term to use when trying to discuss C++ problems accurately, though of course everyone does it.

Comment: Well, there was ever one occurrence of "heap" in some informal text of C++14 draft and I [wiped it out](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/380).

Answer (score 17):

In Herb's book "Exceptional C++", he defines:

**Heap:** A dynamic memory area that is allocated/freed by the `malloc`/`free` functions.

**Free Store:** A dynamic memory area that is allocated/freed by `new`/`delete`.

Its possible for `new` and `delete` to be implemented in terms of `malloc` and `free`, so technically, they could be the same memory area.  However, as the standard doesn't specify this, its best to treat them separatly, and not to mix `malloc`/`delete` or `new`/`free`.

Answer (score 6):

The `free-store` technically isn't the heap, just as local variables technically aren't on the stack. However, it's extremely rare in my experience to find anybody who won't accept those terms.

Comment: please clarify what is the meaning of "local variables technically aren't on the stack".

Comment: @abhinav8: C++ is a high-level programming language that abstracts away such implementation details as physical memory location. Thus, when talking about only C++, _there is no stack_.