# how to intentionally leak non-pointer heap allocated object

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, heap-memory

say I have class Foo which I allocate on the heap via the 'new' keyword. Say Foo has non-pointer data member Bar. Bar, although non-pointer, is itself on the heap since it is a part of Foo. It will be properly deallocated when I delete my Foo object - even if I declare my own Foo destructor that doesn't (wont, and shouldn't) delete Bar.

1. Is there some term for data members like Bar which, although on the heap, isn't created via the "new" keyword? For objects not stack allocated but destructor-calling handled automagically.
2. Is Foo's default destructor still created even though the programmer has declared and defined one, that executes afterward?
3. If not, how does Bar's destructor get called?
4. Given the standards rule that says "the committee shall make no rule that prevents C++ programmers from shooting themselves in the foot," if I WANTED to create a memory leak on a non-pointer data member, whether stack or heap allocated, how would I do so? (Note: I'm not actually trying to do this)

Comment: I think is is important to understand that `bar` is part of `foo`. When a class includes a pointer it is the *pointer* that is a member of `foo`, the thing the pointer points to is not (excepting pathological cases) a part of `foo` even if you `new` it in `foo::c'tor` and `delete` it in `foo::d'tor` (in which case `foo` is responsible for it and notionally owns it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the C++ standard has no heap.  It has the free store, and automatic storage.

Lets look at a concrete example that matches your theoretical one:

```
struct Bar { int x[100]; }
struct Foo {
  Bar bq;
  int x;
  ~Foo() {};
};
```

`Bar bq` is a member variable of any `Foo` instance.  When you create a `Foo` on the free store, its member variables are part of `Foo`.  If `Foo` is standard layout (like above), you are basically guaranteed that its member variables are allocated in a linear buffer.  Non standard layout objects can, in some theoretical compiler, have exotic layouts: but in practice they do not.

With the above `Foo`, no default destructor is created.  However, for every destructor of `Foo`, the objects inside `Foo` are destroyed after the body of `Foo`'s destructor is run.  Note that destroying a pointer does nothing -- I mean the actual objects part of `Foo`.

This isn't because the "default destructor that is automatically created" is called -- the default destructor is `~Foo() {}`, the same as what you defined.  Rather, code automatically runs after the destructor finishes.

The only way to make `Bar`'s destructor not be called would be to make the data member not be `Bar`.  There are a few ways to do this, including creating a `Bar` sized and aligned buffer of data then placement `new`ing the `Bar`.

However, while the destructor will not be called, the memory that `Bar` exists within will be recycled by the free store when the `Foo` `Bar` exists in is recycled.

If you wanted `Bar` to leak, you'd block `Foo` from being returned to the free store.  There is, however, no way to allocate a `Foo` from the free store and return *part* of the `Foo` to the free store -- you are only allowed to return all of it or none.  You could choose to implement your own free store or your own manual heap with these properties, and nothing will stop you.  You can even override `new` and `delete` so that your heap is used instead of the free store when someone does a `Foo* foo = new Foo()`, and when someone does a `delete foo`.

However, the amount of memory that the `Foo` takes up is not within your control, nor the relative location of each member variable.

Comment: great explanation. However, I'm not clear about how C++ has no heap. I thought "free store" and "heap" were synonymous. What's the difference? From what I've gathered, the stack is the first X bytes of memory available to a process and the heap is whatever is beyond that.

Comment: nevermind the last question, found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161235/what-is-the-difference-between-the-heap-and-the-free-store

Answer (score 1):

1) It isn't magic, and there's no term for it. When you allocate space for `Foo`, the `sizeof` `Foo` includes the size of all its data members, and those members are usually byte aligned along 4 byte boundaries. When `delete` is called, the book-keeping header in front of your allocated object will hold the size of the allocation, which will include the `Bar` data member.

2) What do you mean? If a default constructor is created by the user then why would the compiler generate a default constructor?

3) `Bar` is freed because it is a part of a single allocation of `Foo`.

4) You would need to modify the book-keeping structure that surrounds your allocation by hand. This would trick the standard memory manager into thinking your allocation is smaller than it is. Doing this would result in undefined behavior and probably cause a crash.

All of your questions really show that you don't have any idea what `new` or `delete` are doing. I suggest reading up on how construct a simple C++ memory manager.

Comment: I meant default destructor, not constructor.

Comment: Default ctor for Foo or Bar, and what has the user already declared? The question isn't too clear.

Comment: @zeroth Okay, if the user defines a dtor for Foo, then one will not be automatically generated. One may still be generated for Bar though.

Comment: But then what calls Bar's destructor? if not Foo's, then whose?

Comment: Each data member has its destructor called in a order from highest in declared in the file, to lowest when the object it resides in is destructed. Even if you write an empty dtor for Foo, each member including Bar should have its destructor called. You don't have to explicitly call destructors for your members.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can overload the `delete` operator to do nothing, but that would be shooting yourself in the foot quite badly indeed.

I guess if you really wanted you would have the delete operator call a kind of memory manager with a pointer on itself instead of freeing the memory, as part of a pool pattern or something like that. This manager would also be responsible for cleaning up the mess in the end. but is that really worth it?

Edit: Sorry, i didn't read the "non pointer" part, I guess this wouldn't work then.

Answer (score 0):

1) this behaviour is common to all data members - they're included in the class so exist wherever an instance of the class is created.  (Pointer data members themselves are in the class even if they track pointed-to data in a separate part of the heap.)  In terms of terminology, you can say they're "stored by value" using Object Oriented "composition" as distinct from pointed-to or referenced data.

2) Data members have their own constructors that run before the class constructor's body.  You can provide arguments to the data member constructors using the initialiser list ala `Class() : data_member(value) { }`.  Later, the default destructor for the class runs before the default destructor for the data members - that's why having an empty destructor doesn't affect the data member destruction.

3) It's own default destructor runs, and after all the data members and bases of the class are destroyed the memory is deallocated.  For a free-store/heap variable all that is triggered by `delete`.

4) A memory leak is an object which is no longer usable by the program but hasn't and won't be destroyed and deallocated.  The only objects for which automatic destruction/deallocation isn't performed are free-store/heap allocated objects, which can only be created using `new` or `malloc`/`realloc` (or functions that call that such as `strdup`).  So - you have to use pointers (you can store a reference ala `*new X` but that's still dealing with a pointer momentarily.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a reference that is initialised with the new keyword?

AKA:

```
class Foo
{
private:
    Bar& bar;
public:
    Foo() : bar(*new Bar())
    { }
};
```

I think this will work :)

Comment: valgrind confirms it was indeed leaked. I'd like to point out I'm not trying to legitimately do this but understand why or how compilers know to call destructors when the programmer didn't specifically say so, and especially curious if it is possible to leak a stack allocated object's memory. This is heap allocation, and it's clear why it leaks.

Comment: @zeroth Don't forget to tick me :) Glad I could help. Yeah there are some finer subtleties to C++, I hope this answer clarified this one.

Comment: By tick I assume you mean +1 to the top left corner. I don't have enough reputation to do this yet - stackoverflow newb here :)

Comment: @zeroth actually i meant the green tick that you give the answer that best answers your questions. You will see an outline of a tick on the left of each answer in a question you ask. Generally you should end up clicking the one that answers best :)