# CStrings and pointers: Heap corruption when trying to delete a character array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, c-strings

I've exhausted myself googling this, but I haven't been able to find a clear answer or help myself understand what is going wrong. As part of a homework assignment, I'm trying to dynamically allocate memory for a character array (ie. a CString) and assign a char pointer variable to point at it, then delete the allocated memory before I end the program. I'm just wrapping my head around pointers so I suspect that some of my understanding of what's happening behind the scenes is not correct, and I'm ending up with Visual Studio 2010 giving me heap corruption breakpoints.

Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to do (my comments indicate what I *think* I'm doing):

```
char *chPtr = new char[10]; // Create a char pointer type variable, and point it at the memory allocated for a char array of length 10
chPtr = "September";        // Assign 9 characters (+1 null terminator character) to the char array
cout << chPtr;              // Prints "September", then finds the null terminator and stops printing
delete [] chPtr;            // THIS is what causes my heap corruption -> But I don't know why. Shouldn't this delete the array of memory that chPtr is pointing at?
```

- I've tried using `delete chPtr` as well, with the same heap corruption result.
- I've tried manually assigning a null terminator to the end of the array `chPtr[9] = '\0';` , but this also results in heap corruption. Why? I can access individual characters from within the array when I do things like `cout << chPtr[7];` etc without any problems...

What's really confusing is that this works without error:

```
char *chPtr = new char[10]; // As above, create a char pointer type and point it at the memory allocated for a char array of length 10
delete chPtr;               // This doesn't give any error!
```

It seems that initializing the array by assigning a value is breaking things for me somehow.

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the source of your problem:

```
char *chPtr = new char[10]; // Create a char pointer type variable, and point it at the memory allocated for a char array of length 10
chPtr = "September";
```

first you allocate a heap memory on `chPtr` , then allocate a non-heap memory (Data segment memory, if to be precise) by assigning the non-heap char array with the value of "september" on it.

you try to delete non-heap memory , then you get the error you get.

use `strcpy(chPtr,"September")` or even better : lose the C and use `std::string`.

Comment: Ahhh, this makes sense. To help me understand this fully, how would I go about assigning a literal (ie. "September") into the memory allocated by `new`, without the use of strcpy() ?

Comment: C++ knows nothing of heap, non-heap and data segments. `"September"` is not a "temporary string". This is not assigning a string, but a pointer to an array of characters.

Comment: you can't really do it on C or C-like-code since `new char[]` allocate a series of bytes without really asigning them any value. an array of bytes does not have a constructor to work upon, it's just a block of memory. you have to use some memory-copying function like `strcpy` or `memcpy`. you can however create `std::string ` on the heap and assign a literal to it by `new std::string("September")`. this said, `std::string` already keeps its inner buffer on the heap, so there is no actual need to create heap-based std::string

Comment: @isanae I accept your comment, I edited my answer a bit.

Comment: I see. So, to assign values to the memory allocated by `new` without using `strcpy`, I'd need (for example) to create a function that looped through my array index by index (ie memory address by memory address) and manually assigned each char?

Answer (score 1):

`chPtr = "September";` changes where `chPtr` is pointing. Instead of pointing to wherever your array of 10 `char`s was allocated, it is now pointing to the static character array "September". You are then trying to delete that, which fails.

As a test, you can try this:

```
char* p = nullptr;
std::cout << static_cast<void*>(p) << "\n";

p = new char[10];
std::cout << static_cast<void*>(p) << "\n";

p = "September";
std::cout << static_cast<void*>(p) << "\n";
```

A possible output would be:

```
00000000
0068C988
00D18B34
```

You can see that the address where `p` is pointing changes at every assignment. The block allocated on the free store (`0068C988`) is lost on the third assignment.

If you want to assign characters, do something like

```
std::strcpy(chPtr, "September");
```

This comes with all the caveats of memory management, arrays and pointers. What you really want to do is:

```
std::string s = "September";
std::cout << s;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to delete a block of memory where your "September" is located and it's definitely is not allocated in heap, if you need to initialize pre-allocated buffer use strcpy(..) functions.

Comment: There is no *"heap"*, as far as C++ is concerned (at least not the way you are using it). You are probably referring to [*"free store"*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6161235/1889329) instead.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment `chPtr = "September";` doesn't do what you think it does. It assigns the **address** of the static character array `"September"` to the variable `chPtr`. When you try to invoke `operator delete[]` on it, things go wrong: You're trying to delete a statically allocated character array.

If you wish to **copy** characters, you will have to use a string copy function like [std::strcpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy).

Of course, the correct way to use C-style strings in C++ is to not use C-style strings. Use one of the standard C++ [std::basic_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) templates.

Answer (score 0):

`chPtr = "September"` doesn't assign anything to the memory pointed to by `chPtr` instead it assigns `chPtr` to point to some other memory that does hold "September". You can't delete this memory.

Comment: you mean the Data segment. "September" does not sit on the stack